# Combine value of two cell and eliminate duplicate creating addition columns with unique value

Tags: excel

This is a bit like an earlier question. I have a spread sheet that has multiple divisions going down in rows, each row has one person and relevant information for the employees. I have used a formula to eliminate all the duplicate divisions. I am trying to create summary information from the divisions.

```
My division were consolidated with the formula =INDEX($F$2:$F$587,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($J$1:J1,$F$2:$F$587),0))
```

Now I have been trying to expand formula so that Unique value are created. I would like to compare the Value of "F" AND the value of "G" and create additional columns with and entry for each unique value and count how many were found. I would like to do this for the VALUES of `F2:F588` AND `G2:G588` and the derived values placed in `J:24:588` or until the end of the `"ENDIF"`.

This goal is to count how many persons in the organization are in a Division within a payband  FOR EACH DIVISON BY PAYBAND-- I know it has to be something I am overlooking but try as I may I FAIL..  See the image.

[image]

Comment: At that point it will be easier to copy the range and paste the values then use Remove Duplicates.  Or you will need to write vba to do it.

Comment: The problem with counting and reduce duplicates is that there are 588 rows, I can reduce/eliminate the duplicate divisions  easily enough, however take the Divison BH for example, the have 7 employees with grade 7 and many more at level to. So comparing the values of BH and 7 to consolidate the entry  to ONE where is appears as something as shown in the result balloon is the choice, that why should any information in the division code or pay level change the change would be reflected without having to recount.